# Enviar valor de variavel de uma página php externa para um campo em um html externo

Tags: php, html

Estou com dificuldades em enviar o valor de uma variavél que está no PHP para uma página externa HTML.

Tenho a página **executa.php** e tenho a página **call.html**.

**call.html** envia para **executa.php**, que envia para **segue.html** a informação abaixo segue meu código:

#### Primeira página call.html

```html
<form method=post name="formulario" action="executa.php">
   <!-- Telefone -->
   <input type="text" name="numerotelefone">
   <p class="tamanho">*Preenchimento Obrigat&oacute;rio</p><BR>
   <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" align="right" width="48" height="48">
</form>
```

#### Segunda página executa.php

```
<?php
#Campo de Busca Telefone
$telefone = $_POST['numerotelefone'];
echo "Telefone Informado: <pre>$telefone</pre>";  
header('refresh:3;url=ativar.html?&numerotelefone='.$telefone);
?>
```

#### Terceira página segue.html

```html
<!-- Aqui recebo o telefone da página executa.php -->
<input id="field_1" type="text" name="field_1" value="<?php echo $telefone ?>" />
```

Depois que a página **executa.php** é exibida, ela chama a página **segue.html** nesse ponto não consigo enviar o valor da variável `$telefone` que foi recebida na **executa.php** para **segue.html**

Comment: A página segue.html não irá rodar o código PHP em `value="<?php echo $telefone ?>"` porque é uma página .html comum. Vc vai ter que usar JavaScript pra pegar na URL o número do telefone. Por que não usa uma página PHP segue.php em vez de segue.html?

Comment: porque dentro da segue.html utilizo o form com radiobutton entre outros elementos.. teria que mudar o projeto todo, em java script estou pesquisando agora que me informou, achei que fosse possivel manter em html mesmo assim obrigado pela dica

Comment: Cara, alterar a página de .html pra .php não muda nada o HTML e ainda vc conseguirá usar códigos PHP dentro dela, o que é melhor ainda.

Comment: vou testar aqui pera e

Comment: funcionouuu man!! VALEUUU